# How do I get a h1 on top of an image, a paragraph in the middle and make the image darker?

Tags: html, css

Currently working on getting some text ONTOP of an image and make the image a bit darker.

However, what I try doesn't seem to work. I cannot get the image darker, and the text either get's above or below the image, but not on top as I try to do.

the RED square = the image, the black square will be the placing of the H1 (TRANSPARANT).

HTML:

```
 <div id="mainarticle">
            <a href="artikels.html"> 
                <img src="images/interview.jpg">
                <div id="ontop">
                <h3> Lol </h3>  
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

CSS :

```
#ontop {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#mainarticle img {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLf2jme3/)

[image: Example]

Comment: You can use `position: absolute;` to put the text on top. Then use `top: 0; left: 0;` to move it to the top left corner. Change the '0' to whatever position you desire. To make the image darker you could use `filter: brightness(50%)` and change the percentage to whatever suits your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` for text:

```
#ontop {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
```

and additional div with black background (class "darker")
See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/smollet92/uLf2jme3/6/

Answer (score 0):

When you want to overlap two elements in a web page, you have to use a positioned parent (wrapper) for both, and use one of them to size the parent while stretching the other over the entire space of the parent, using:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

which will effectively make it cover (and get rendered all over) the positioned parent.

This method is useful when you want one element to set the size of the container while having the other cover the resulting area.

```css
.article {
  position: relative;
}
.article img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
.ontop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300">    
  <a href class="ontop"> 
      <div >
        <h3> Lol </h3>  
      </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

In your specific case, if you want the resulting element to have a determined height (`100vh`), you can simply set that value as `min-height` on the child and use `background-image` on the parent, without the need to overlap anything or use `position`-ing:

```css
.article {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/800/600) no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
}
.ontop {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.ontop h1 {
  top: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.65);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <a href class="ontop"> 
    <h1>This would be a title</h1>
      <div >
        <h3> Lol </h3>  
      </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Note**: to give you more insight on `position`-ing I used it slightly differently in the second example, for positioning the `<h1>` element inside the `<a>`.

Comment: There must be 1000 dupe links for this one....took me 2 sec. to find one of them

Comment: @LG, you're correct (like always). I felt generous today, for no particular reason.

Comment: LOL............